# If one zookeeper dies, what behavior shall I expect?

Tags: client, apache-zookeeper

Is there a way we can create watch on zookeeper serevers themselves? If i have 5 zookeeper servers, and if one follower dies what behavior shall I expect? Would the existing requestes be aborted? Or another zookeeper would take care of these?

How should the client can be moved to another zookeeper transparently?

Meena

Comment: Hi @MeenaRajani, do you use a supervisory process to manage your Zookeepers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way we can create watch on zookeeper serevers themselves?

No, watches are set only on znodes, which are the items of data written by clients to the ZooKeeper cluster.  There is no mechanism for a client to receive automatic notification of a server in the cluster stopping.

> If i have 5 zookeeper servers, and if one follower dies what behavior shall I expect?

Clients that were connected to the follower when it died will reconnect to the ZooKeeper cluster using a different server.  As long as there is still a quorum of available servers, the cluster will remain functional for both read and write traffic.  If that server later restarts and comes back online, then it will re-synchronize with a good server to catch up on missed transactions.

> Would the existing requestes be aborted? Or another zookeeper would take care of these?  How should the client can be moved to another zookeeper transparently?

For a correctly coded ZooKeeper client application, the error handling will reconnect to a different server in the cluster and proceed with its transactions.  The ZooKeeper client internally heartbeats with the server it is connected to.  If the connection is lost, there is a "connection loss" event dispatched to the client.  This is an opportunity for the client to re-establish any state required.

For more details, I recommend reading through the [ZooKeeper Programmer's Guide](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.10/zookeeperProgrammers.html) and [Recipes and Solutions](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.10/recipes.html), which contain working examples of typical use cases with correct error handling and recovery.  Another potential consideration is to use the [Apache Curator](http://curator.apache.org/) library, which has working implementations of higher-level constructs like distributed locks, with correct error handling and recovery.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Just a follow up, do  I have to write client code for randomly connecting to a zookeeper node in ensemble? Is there any API  which helps  the client request to distribute evenly to each zookeeper node? Also if one zookeeper fails from the ensemble, and we get the "connection loss" event,  should the client code resend the request to another zookeeper explicitly? Or if there is some library which can be used here?

Comment: @MeenaRajani , you do not have to randomly select a ZooKeeper node.  Instead, pass a comma-separated list of multiple ZooKeeper server addresses to the `ZooKeeper` constructor.  You won't need to handle load distribution or node selection yourself.  After connection loss, you can simply retry your operations without explicitly selecting a server.

Comment: @MeenaRajani, if this was helpful, then please consider accepting the answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers